# How to create google sign in/up button in android using XML?

Tags: xml, android-layout, button

I don't want to use **any image** in my Android App

is there any way to  make it with **XML** only ?
  [image]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to create same view in xml layout

main.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_15"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_15">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_5">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SIGN IN/UP WITH GOOGLE"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_google"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dimen_13"
                    android:gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

[image: Screen Shot]